# JButton disparar dois eventos diferentes?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Tenho um programinha que simula um jogo de dados, onde eu tenho dois "dados" que, quando a soma dos dois dá 7, o usuário é ganhador, se não, ele perde.

Pois bem, fiz uma interface simples no `swing`, onde criei dois botões, um lança o primeiro valor usando a classe `Random`, e outro botão que lança um segundo valor, e mais um que trás o resultado.

Gostaria de saber se é possível, e se for, como fazer para o usuário clicar em apenas um botão, para disparar os dois valores, ele clica uma vez, dispara o valor do primeiro dado, e ele clica outra, e dispara o valor do segundo dado.
Obrigada!

Segue código da Tela:

```
public class JDialogJogar extends javax.swing.JDialog {

    /**
     * Creates new form Jogo
     */
    public JDialogJogar(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
        super(parent, modal);
        initComponents();
    }

    int numero1;
    int numero2;

    public void jogarDado1() {

        try {

            Random gerador1 = new Random();
            numero1 = gerador1.nextInt(7) + 1;          


            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Dado 1: " + numero1);
            int dado1 = numero1;
            txtDado1.setText(String.valueOf(numero1));
            travarDado1();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Erro" + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    public void jogarDado2() {

        try {

            Random gerador = new Random();
            numero2 = gerador.nextInt(7 + 1);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Dado 2: " + numero2);
            int dado2 = numero2;
            txtDado2.setText(String.valueOf(numero2));
            travarDado2();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Erro" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void mostrarResultado() {

        int resultado = numero1 + numero2;

        if ((numero1 + numero2) == 7) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Resultado: " + resultado + " Parabéns! Você Ganhou!");
            destravar();
            limpar();

        } else {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Resultado: " + resultado + " Você Perdeu!");
            destravar();
            limpar();

        }

    }
```

Da ação do botão:

```
private void btnResultadoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        mostrarResultado();
    }                                            

    private void btnJogarDado1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        jogarDado1();

    }                                             

    private void btnJogarDado2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        jogarDado2();
    }
```

Comment: Você quer que com um clique, dispare o dado 1 e 2 ou com cliques diferentes?

Comment: Quero que com um clique, dispare o dado 1, e com outro clique, dispare o dado 2.

Comment: Os dados podem continuar sendo disparados livremente após ja terem sido disparados uma vez cada um?

Comment: Podem Sim!------

Answer (score 1):

Crie uma variável booleana na sua classe `JDialogJogar` para controlar quando o botão já foi clicado anteriormente:

```
boolean hasBeenClicked = false;
```

E no `actionPerformed()` do botão que acionará os dados, cheque se o botão já foi clicado anteriormente, alterando a variável acima, como se fosse um "interruptor":

```
private void btnJogarDadosActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    if(!hasBeenClicked) {
       jogarDado1();
       hasBeenClicked = true;

    } else {
       jogarDado2();
       hasBeenClicked = false;  
}
```

A variável `hasBeenClicked` vai controlar quando o botão foi clicado anteriormente, indicando qual dos dois métodos deverá ser disparado, e após o segundo método ser executado, setamos como `false` para "limpar" a informação para outro ciclo de 2 jogadas.

Comment: Muito obrigada!
Funcionou perfeitamente!
Abraços